# Custom Design in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

the landing page of Material UI has slick design (both layout and components). I wonder if I can use this design instead of default Material Design. I couldn't find any information about this design in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for the source code of `mui` documentation website. Here's the [link](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/docs/src)

If you are looking for theme specifically then this [link](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/modules/brandingTheme.ts) should help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean their home page, it's actually designed by Material UI, you can check this by seeing the source page.
Mostly Material UI components in the home page are designed using `makeStyle` so they are not in the default style.
https://mui.com/styles/api/#heading-makestyles-styles-options-hook